# Consultar REST API en C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, api

Cree una API en NodeJS con db en Mongo que devuelve por ejemplo en esta URL (http://localhost:8001/categorias) un array en JSON de categorias por ejemplo:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "cantidad": 5,
    "categorias": [
        {
            "_id": "5fac0163ac7fe522acc202c3",
            "nombre": "Aperitivos"
        }
    ]
}
```

Y estoy tratando de obtenerme los resultados de esta manera (todavía tengo el código en el controller, ya lo voy a pasar a un servicio pero estoy probando unicamente)

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private const string URL = "http://localhost:8001";
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{URL}/categoria");

            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // List data response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Categoria>>().Result;  
                foreach (var d in dataObjects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.nombre);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
            client.Dispose();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

La clase Categoria es así:

```
public class Categoria
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public bool estado { get; set; }
    }
```

Me devuelve una respuesta, pero al llegar a la línea:
`var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Categoria>>().Result;`

Tengo un error como este:

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'
JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AdminLTE.Models.Categoria]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'ok', line 1, position 6.
```

Alguien sabe que pasa? Instale Newtosoft.Json, System.Net.Http.Formatting y System.Net.Http.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El formato del json debe coincidir con la clase a mapear. El json es un objeto que adentro tiene un arreglo y la clase `Categoria` no tiene esa estructura, para que encaje debería ser una clase, por ejemplo `Respuesta`, con un arreglo de categorías en su interior, replicando la estructura de la respuesta json.

```
    public class Categoria
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public bool estado { get; set; }
        
    }
    
    public class Respuesta{
      public bool ok {get;set;}
      public int cantidad {get;set;}
      public List<Categoria> categorias {get;set;}
    }
```

Mapeo de la respuesta:

```
    var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Respuesta>().Result;  
    foreach (var d in dataObjects.categorias)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.nombre);
    }
```

Comment: Claro! Estaba cambiando los nombres de las propiedades dentro de categoria pero no me di cuenta que la respuesta de la API tambien tenia el ok y cantidad! Muchisimas gracias.